# Lattice QCD and the 5th dimension

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, fermions, lattice-model

I was digging into the [Nielsen-Ninomiya Theorem](http://latticeqcd.blogspot.com/2005/12/nielsen-ninomiya-theorem.html) and doubler fermions, as well as solutions to these problems using [Domain Wall Fermions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9410018) and [overlap lattice fermions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0405024), both of which make effective use of a 5th dimension.

Does this imply that our universe is either a continuous 3+1 dimensional space, or a space that is 4+1 dimensions on a lattice?